# Django - FileField - PDF vs octet-stream - AWS S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I have a model with a file field like so:

```py
class Document(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(...)
```

Elsewhere in my application, I am trying to download a pdf file from an external url and upload it to the file field:

```py
import requests
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

...

# get the external file:
response = requests.get('<external-url>')

# convert to ContentFile:
file = ContentFile(response.content, name='document.pdf')

# update document:
document.file.save('document.pdf', content=file, save=True)
```

However, I have noticed the following behavior:

- files uploaded via the django-admin portal have the `content_type` "application/json"
- files uploaded via the script above have the `content_type` "application/octet-stream"

How can I ensure that files uploaded via the script have the "application/pdf" `content_type`? Is it possible to set the `content_type` on the the `ContentFile` object? This is important for the frontend.

Other notes:

- I am using AWS S3 as my file storage system.
- Uploading a file from my local file storage via the scirpt (i.e. using `with open(...) as file:` still uploads a file as "applicaton/octet-stream"

Comment: For the purposes of this question - the difference is that one content-type triggers an automatic download when an href link is clicked, while the other will open the pdf as a link in the browser

Answer (score 0):

The solution, get this, is to simply add a `content_type` attribute to the `ContentFile` instance:

```py
import requests
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

...

# get the external file:
response = requests.get('<external-url>')

# convert to ContentFile:
file = ContentFile(response.content, name='document.pdf')
file.content_type = "application/pdf"  # <-- this

# update document:
document.file.save('document.pdf', content=file, save=True)
```